# Python -Filtering links from user inputted data

Tags: python, html

What is a safe an efficient way to filter links from user inputted data, and create an anchor link that is then used in the html. Like how when writing a question, and you copy-paste a link, it automatically becomes an anchor link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Gruber's regular expression](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) to find the URIs.

```
import re

text = "foo http://www.stackoverflow.com bar"

uri_re = re.compile(r"""(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|"""
                    r"""www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?"""
                    r""":[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))"""
                    r"""*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|"""
                    r"""[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))""")

print uri_re.sub(r"""<a href="\g<0>">\g<0></a>""", text)
```

Result:

```
foo <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a> bar
```

Now the Gruber regex will actually match partial URIs such as `www.stackoverflow.com` (this is missing the `http://` scheme), which won't work when you just stick it into an anchor tag.  You can write a function that checks for that and adds it where necessary, then use that to do the replacement:

```
text = "foo www.stackoverflow.com bar"

def link(match):
    uri = match.group()
    if ":" not in uri[:7]:
        uri = "http://" + uri
    return r"""<a href="{0}">{0}</a>""".format(uri)

print uri_re.sub(link, text)
```

Comment: Should you escape/sanitize text before you run this script on it?

Comment: I'd sanitize first, fix up the links after.

Comment: What do you mean by fix up the links?

Comment: By fix up the links I mean the stuff I posted in my answer: adding HTML markup to turn the naked URIs into links.